# How to create multiple master editions NFT from metaplex sdk

Tags: metaplex, nft, sdk, master-edition

What parameter should I need to pass in [await metaplex.nfts().create({})] in order  to create number of master editions . I see the maxSupply represents the number of print editions .

Answer (score 1):

An nft will only have a single "master edition" account, which is a PDA derived using the nft's mint address.

Use `printNewEdition` if you're trying to print an "edition" of an nft.

```
const { nft: printedNft } = await metaplex.nfts().printNewEdition({
    originalMint: originalNft.mint
});
```

Check out the metaplex docs which has great explanations/diagrams for the relationship between accounts: https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/accounts

> The Master Edition account, derived from a Mint Account, is an
> important component of NFTs because its existence is proof of the
> Non-Fungibility of the token.
>
> When creating a Master Edition account, the Token Metadata program
> will check for the following conditions:
>
> - The Mint Account has zero decimals, i.e. Decimals = 0.
> - The MintAccount minted exactly one token to a wallet, i.e. Supply =
>   1.
>
> Additionally, it will transfer the Mint Authority and the Freeze
> Authority to the Master Edition account to prevent anyone from being
> able to mint additional tokens. You can read more about why these
> authorities are transferred instead of being voided in the FAQ.
>
> Therefore, what we end up with is a Mint Account whose supply will
> never go above one and whose token cannot be shared or divided. As
> such, we end up with a Non-Fungible Token (NFT).
>
> On top of being a Non-Fungible proof, the Master Edition allows NFTs
> to be printed a limited or unlimited amount of times. The Master
> Edition NFT acts as the "original record" of the digital asset that
> can be duplicated or "printed" into Edition NFTs. This allows creators
> to offer more than one copy of their digital assets to their audience.
>
> The optional Max Supply field of the Master Edition account tells us
> how many copies of the NFT can be created. When set to None, an
> unlimited amount of copies can be created. When set to zero, the NFT
> cannot be copied.